# Make WebView width stretch before url content is loaded

Tags: android, android-layout, webview

Here is my view XML

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
/>
```

I'm loading a html that has a media query which looks for a screen size and if it's under xyz it hides some elements. My webview has a width of 0 when content is loaded. Is it possible to make webview stretch before content is loaded?

This is how I setup my webview in activity

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.comments_web_view);
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(Globals.kGlobalUserAgent); 

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() 
{
    @Override 
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
    {
       return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }
}); 
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: y u r saying webview wisth is zero as u have set its width as match_parent.

Comment: when I call webview.getWidth() I get 0. I guess it doesn't stretch until content is loaded